# Usage of "shall we?"

Tags: american-english, phrases, british-english, modal-verbs

What does it mean and where would I use it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are in a situation where a group is gathering to do something (go out for lunch, start a meeting, etc.), "Shall we?" would mean something like "Are we now all ready and is it now time to proceed with what we are here for?".  (Or more simply, "Should we now proceed?", but that explains "shall" in terms of "should".)

Comment: and it doesn't suppose to have a reply, right?

Comment: If someone says "shall we?", the usual response in my area of New England is actually "we shall" or just "let's".

Answer (score 6):

*Shall* is used in questions indicating offers or suggestions.

> Shall I send you the book?

> Shall we go?

Comment: According to OED.

Comment: According to NOAD.

Comment: According to both:)

Answer (score 1):

*Shall we* is a polite expression for *Let’s go.* A Spanish equivalent would be *Vámanos.*

Comment: I would add the adjective, deferential, as well. And, indeed, the interrogative (in contradiction of "Parts of Speech"), has been transformed by the asking (by the pretense) into an imperative.